TypeError: myClass.getId is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
I am trying to call java function in karate framework.
Karate scenario
Scenario:
* def myClass = Java.type("package.classname")
* def id = myClass.getId()
* print id

Java function
public String getId(){
  return "1234"
}

I am getting this exception although I am not using js anywhere:
evaluation (js) failed: myClass.getId(), javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: myClass.getId is not a function in <eval> at line number 1

Edit: The code works when the java method is made static. Does method always has to be static to use the function in karate?

Behind the scenes the Java calls are actually JS calls. This error could be because you got the name wrong, or the classpath is wrong, or the method is not public.
